# Lua hexadecimal string every two characters insert a character

Tags: lua, hex

In Lua I have the following hexadecimal string

```
local string="7661722061737472696e673d226c6f6c223b"
```

How can I introduce / insert "%" as a separator between every two characters.

I want it to look like this.

```
%76%61%72%20%61%73%74%72%69%6e%67%3d%22%6c%6f%6c%22%3b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use [`string.gsub`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) to replace a matching pattern with the captured string and your separator. The resulting string will have a preceding separator which can be removed by taking a slice of the string from the beginning plus the length of the separator.

See [§6.4.1 – Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) for a better understanding of pattern matching.

```
local function sep (str, patt, re)
    return str:gsub(patt, '%' .. re .. '%1'):sub(1 + #re)
end

print(sep('7661722061737472696e673d226c6f6c223b', '%x%x', '%'))
--> 76%61%72%20%61%73%74%72%69%6e%67%3d%22%6c%6f%6c%22%3b
```

An alternative way would be to *split* the string into a table, and then use [`table.concat`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.concat) to join the table into a string.

The exhaustive way would be to count every *nth* character in a loop, and take string slices, concatenating with the result thus far and the separator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with `gsub`:

```
s="7661722061737472696e673d226c6f6c223b"
t=s:gsub("..","%%%1")
print(t)
```

It reads: match two characters and replace them with `%` and the match, thus prepending `%` to the two characters.